# Component won't recognize it's being exported

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, debugging, react-native

I've encountered a very strange error.  I feel that I've exported the `Home` component in a normal and conventional manner.  Below, I've posted the `.js` files that I think are relevant in order to rectify this error.  Despite this, In my `iOS` simulator, I'm still getting an error that says:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or 
a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.  You 
likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Check the render method of 'Home'.
```

Here's `Home.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'native-base';
import MapContainer from "../../../components/MapContainer/index";

class Home extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.setName();
    }

    render() {
        const region = {
            latitude: 3.146642,
            longitude: 101.695845,
            latitudeDelta: 0.8922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421
        }
        return(
            <Container>
                <MapContainer region={region}/>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Here's `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import View from 'native-base';
import styles from './MapContainerStyles';
import * as MapView from "react-native-maps/lib/components/ProviderConstants";

const MapContainer = ({region}) => {
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={styles.map}
                region={region}
            >
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
}

export default MapContainer;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't your export of `Home`. We know that because `Home`'s `render` is being called.

From the error, it looks like either `Container` or `MapContainer` isn't being imported correctly. I suspect it's that `Container` is a named export, so you need to use a named import:

```
import { Container } from 'native-base';
```

**Update:** Yup, here's an example from the [NativeBase documentation](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.7/customize):

> ```
> import {Container, Content, Text} from 'native-base';
> ```

Comment: Ok, I did that.  But now I'm getting the same error that says to check render method of `MapContainer` instead of `Home.js`.

Comment: @hop38: It'll be the same sort of error on another import in the `MapContainer` code.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're saying.  Originally, I wanted to import `MapContainer` like so: `import MapContainer from './MapContainer'` but it won't let me.  The way it's being imported now is the suggestion the `WebStorm` IDE gave me.  I have a feeling this has something to do with the error I'm getting.

Comment: @hop38: Well, it's not going to be the `MapContainer` import (just like it wasn't the `Home` import), because `MapContainer`'s `render` is being called (just like `Home`'s was). As I said above, look for a similar `import` error **in** the `MapContainer` code.

Comment: I believe it's the way I'm importing `MapView`.  At first, I tried `import MapView from 'react-native-maps` but then in WebStorm I get an error that says `Default export is not declared in imported module`.  The way I'm imported `MapView` in my original post is again WebStorms suggestion.